# FloatingActionButton Rendering problems after updated gradle dependencies 23.0.2

Tags: android, android-layout, android-support-library, android-support-design

Updating my build.gradle(Module: app) dependencies to 23.2.0, **Getting Rendering Problems classes could not be instantiated: android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton** where ever fab button is their in entire project.

```
  dependencies {
            compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
            compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0'
            ...
            compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.0'
    }
```

**AppTheme**: Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar

**Android Studio Version** : 1.4

**An example of my layout**

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipToPadding="false">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false">
                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                            android:id="@+id/list_buildings"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/_18"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_add_white_24dp"
            android:transitionName="fab"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/fab_button_color"
            app:elevation="@dimen/_04"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: `23.2.0` buggy switch to `23.1.0`

Comment: You should add the "compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'" dependency as well.

Comment: I am using com.android.support:design:23.2.0 as dependency in my project @Egor

Comment: Is their any bug in 23.2.0? @ Intelli Amiya